# How to deserialize an XML document into a List<> while overriding the item names

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

I am trying to deserialize an XML document into a List<>. My goal is the have the List<> have a public static method that returns itself populated from the XML document.

Here is the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
    <item>
        <name>Blue</name>
    </item>
    <item>
        <name>Red</name>
    </item>
</root>
```

Here is the class for the item (BillingItem.cs):

```
using System;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace DeserializeExample
{
    [Serializable]
    [XmlRoot("item")]
    public class BillingItem
    {
        [XmlElement("name")]
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Here is the class that is the list (BillingItems.cs):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace DeserializeExample
{
    [Serializable]
    [XmlRoot("root")]
    public class BillingItems : List<BillingItem>
    {
        public static BillingItems GetBillingItems()
        {
            using (TextReader reader = new StreamReader("BillingItems.xml"))
            {
                XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(BillingItems));
                return (BillingItems)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the console app with an example of how I would like to be able to get the list (Program.cs):

```
namespace DeserializeExample
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            BillingItems billingItems = BillingItems.GetBillingItems();
        }
    }
}
```

When the console app runs, the list is empty. I think it's related to how I am using the attributes, but I am unable to determine how to make this work.

I hope the example is simple, explained well, and that someone can help.

Answer (score 3):

I would *encapsulate* the list - in part for simplicity (avoiding some gnarly overloads the the `XmlSerializer` constructor), and in part because there are some glitches here on CF etc that make it unreliable. But:

```
public class BillingItem
{
    [XmlElement("name")]
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
[XmlRoot("root")]
public class MyResult
{
    [XmlElement("item")]
    public List<BillingItem> Items { get; set; }
}
```

(I have removed all unnecessary other attributes)

You then just return a `MyResult` (named more appropriately, obviously), and it will serialize as per your example.

Comment: Thank you for your response, and I have considered doing that as that will indeed work. However, I didn't mention this in my original post to keep it simple, but, I am adding new features to an existing application that utilizes the CSLA framework. In that framework lists of things are implemented as a special list (BusinessListBase) in which every list of things has a public static method that will return a list of itself. So I would need to avoid using an encapsulating class as you suggest.

Comment: @Doug all I can say there is that it is often necessary (and indeed desirable) to have a subtly different representation of things at serialization boundaries, versus in your core application. I would simply write this off as an example of the above (and wrap just before it goes through the serialization layer). That's what I'd do, at least.

Comment: I understand, but an entire application has been build built knowing that if you need a list of 'things' you simply call Things.GetThings() and a list of Thing objects is returned. Breaking that convention would require huge huge hours of refactoring. Something tells me there is a simple answer to this problem. But I appreciate your help thus far.

Comment: @Doug I don't see why that would be impacted

Comment: @Doug, if thats the case why cant you deserialise it in the method and then return MyResult.Items instead of MyResult?

Answer (score 1):

From your example it looks like serialization may not be necessary. If it isn't, consider parsing using LINQ-to-XML:

```
using System.Xml.Linq;

public class BillingItems : List<BillingItem>
{
    // Constructor.
    private BillingItems(List<BillingItem> items) : base(items) { }

    public static BillingItems GetBillingItems()
    {
        var doc = XDocument.Load("BillingItems.xml");
        var items = (from i in doc.Element("root").Elements("item")
                        select new BillingItem { Description = i.Element("name").Value })
                    .ToList();
        return new BillingItems(items);
    }
}
```

You may also want to consider using an IEnumerable<> rather than a List<> unless you plan on inserting/removing items.

EDIT: Modified the above code so that BillingItems inherits a List<>, per the OP's comment below.

Comment: Thanks and I can see what you are doing. But this doesn't compile, due to the caller expecting to be able instantiate a BillingItems object and getting a new one (see the console app above). If I change the BillingItems class as you suggest it results in the following error: Error 1 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<DeserializeExample.BillingItem>' to 'DeserializeExample.BillingItems' C:\Users\doug.ramirez\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\DeserializeExample\DeserializeExample\Program.cs 9 32 DeserializeExample

Comment: Hi Doug, I've modified the above code snippet per your comment. Please try it out. It isn't quite ideal because the constructor has to copy all of the items from one List<> to another, but it may meet your needs.

Comment: Kevin, I didn't see your post until I posted my solution this morning (see below).  Your solution works perfectly, thank you. I'm going to try and implement your design in my app and see how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, while I don't like this because I believe there is something in the XmlSerializer that will do this for me, ug, but in the meantime I am going to do the following.

Adding an encapsulating class with the list I really want:

```
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace DeserializeExample
{
    [XmlRoot("root")]
    public class BillingItemResult
    {
        [XmlElement("item")]
        public BillingItems Items { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Then in my BillItems.cs class the private static void method will get the encapsulating object and return it's list of billing items:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace DeserializeExample
{
    [Serializable]
    [XmlRoot("root")]
    public class BillingItems : List<BillingItem>
    {
        public static BillingItems GetBillingItems()
        {
            using (TextReader reader = new StreamReader("BillingItems.xml"))
            {
                XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(BillingItemResult));
                BillingItemResult billingItemResult = (BillingItemResult)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
                return billingItemResult.Items;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This allows the design and convention of the existing application to remain intact. Here is a sample from the CLI:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
namespace DeserializeExample
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            BillingItems billingItems = BillingItems.GetBillingItems();
        }
    }
}
```

While this works, I still believe there is something more simple that doesn't require the additional wrapping class.